# Nightly "publish build" in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I manage a CI-server for a bunch of projects of my company, running under CruiseControl.NET 1.6.7981.1. The projects logically form a "product", but are (at least partially) independent from each other. As comparison, MS Office is a "product" consisting of the independent projects "Word", "Excel", etc.

Each project has its own ccnet-project which get build whenever a change is committed to source-control (via IntervalTrigger). This works fine.

The product itself consists of the output of the different "child" projects as well as additional static data (bitmaps, sample data, ...). For this I have a separate "publish" ccnet-project which does these steps and then copies the data to a new output folder on the network. This "publishing" works fine as well. Each time it is run, a new folder is created; currently each folder is approx. 1GB in size.

I have two additional requirements:

1. Since "publish" generates such huge amounts of data, I want to run it nightly (unless someone manually triggers it). We actually have two versions of the product and all child projects running on the CI-server (dev and last-release). The last-release gets patches only, so there might be several days when nothing has been done in the child-projects. So "publish" should only run if a child-project has been modified.
2. Someone might break the build of one of the child-projects. Until it is fixed, the parent "publish" project should not be run.

The way I tried to solve it does not work correctly, however. My current ccnet.config looks approx. as follows (relevant parts only):

```
<project name="Child 1 dev" queue="dev" queuePriority="1">
    <!-- Build the project -->
    <publishers>
        <!-- Logger, statistics, ... -->
        <conditional>
            <conditions>
                <statusCondition value="Success" />
                <lastStatusCondition value="Failure" />
            </conditions>
            <tasks>
                <cruiseServerControl>
                    <actions>
                        <controlAction type="StartProject" project="Publish dev" />
                    </actions>
                </cruiseServerControl>
            </tasks>
        </conditional>
        <conditional>
            <conditions>
                <statusCondition value="Failure" />
            </conditions>
            <tasks>
                <cruiseServerControl>
                    <actions>
                        <controlAction type="StopProject" project="Publish dev" />
                    </actions>
                </cruiseServerControl>
            </tasks>
        </conditional>
    </publishers>
</project>

<!-- Additional "child" projects as above -->

<project name="Publish dev" queue="dev" queuePriority="10">
    <triggers>
        <multiTrigger operator="And">
            <triggers>
                <multiTrigger operator="Or">
                    <triggers>
                        <projectTrigger project="Child 1" />
                        <projectTrigger project="Child 2" />
                        <projectTrigger project="Child 3" />
                    </triggers>
                </multiTrigger>
                <scheduleTrigger buildCondition="ForceBuild" time="23:30" />
            </triggers>
        </multiTrigger>
    </triggers>
    <!-- Do the publishing, a bunch of exec tasks. -->
</project>
```

The problems:

1. If nothing is done in the child projects for several days, then no "publish" is run. After this, as soon as something changes in the child projects, "publish" runs. I am guessing that the ScheduleTrigger is staying triggered. I tried wrapping the ScheduleTrigger in a FilterTrigger, but then sometimes no build ran at all.
2. If the build of a child project fails, the publish project is stopped. However, starting the project again after the build has succeeded often doesn't work.

So in short, I guess the solution would a set of triggers for "publish dev" which triggers:

1. Each night at 23:30 (for example).
2. When any child project has been successfully built since the previous "publish dev".
3. And no child project is in a build-failed state (i.e. all child projects are in a successful build state).

If #2 or #3 are wrong, the next check should only be the next night.

EDIT:

Something definitely wrong with the lastStatusCondition. I have the following outputs:

Failed build:

```
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking conditions
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking status - matching to Success
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Conditions did not pass - running else tasks
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Tasks completed: 0 successful, 0 failed
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking conditions
2011-04-01 10:14:06,105 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking status - matching to Failure
2011-04-01 10:14:06,121 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Conditions passed - running tasks
```

So everything is working fine. Then I immediately build it again, with build fixed:

```
2011-04-01 10:18:36,078 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking conditions
2011-04-01 10:18:36,078 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking status - matching to Success
2011-04-01 10:18:36,078 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking last build status - matching to Failure
2011-04-01 10:18:36,078 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Conditions did not pass - running else tasks
2011-04-01 10:18:36,093 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Tasks completed: 0 successful, 0 failed
2011-04-01 10:18:36,093 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking conditions
2011-04-01 10:18:36,093 [Child 1 dev] [DEBUG] - Checking status - matching to Failure
2011-04-01 10:18:36,093 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Conditions did not pass - running else tasks
2011-04-01 10:18:36,093 [Child 1 dev] [INFO] - Tasks completed: 0 successful, 0 failed
```

So despite the previous build having failed (as you can see from the matching to Failure in the first log), the previous build status property of the current (successful) build apparently is not Failure! I guess I'll have to file a bug against ccnet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my blog, I provided a solution there. Comments are appreciated :

http://rubenwillems.blogspot.com/2011/04/tuning-ccnet-to-your-whishes-new.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have to test if it works as planned. Minor correction: In `SubProjectsAreChanged()`, you immediately return true if a subproject has been built in the meantime. However, a not-yet-checked subproject may be in a failed state. Locally I changed it to save this to a temporary variable and return it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, my thought are like yours : I think the schedule trigger keeps fired and waits for the multiple "OR trigger" to be fired. Note that this behaviour is expected when you reverse role : when a child project is successfully build you want to wait until the second trigger fires (at 23:30).

A couple of idea to fit your requirements would be :

- Add the <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus> to the project triggers (to prevent exceptions)
- Set the innerTrigger of the project triggers to a schedule trigger instead of the default interval trigger. A schedule trigger set to fire at 23:30 should solve your problem

As for your second problem, I have no idea why the project would not restart, sowwy.

I personnaly managed to deal with these products problem with [Enterprise Continuous Integration](http://mikebroberts.com/articles/enterprise-continuous-integration-using-binary-dependencies/), we used it for almost a year and it's great relief.

Comment: For the second problem, my guess is that perhaps lastStatusCondition doesn't work properly per project but rather is "global". So if another projects runs successfully in the meantime, the last status is set to success, even though the last status of the project should continue to be "failed".

Comment: There is one problem when using a project trigger: The first time the inner trigger fires, it has no previous state as comparison. So it does not know what to do. That is no problem with the default interval trigger (as it is fired every 5 seconds). But that means for the schedule trigger that after a server restart we either wait an additional day, or always trigger (even if it weren't necessary).